# Not displaying ErrorMsg for long lines only with tex, md and calendar buffers

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, terminal

I use and love the plugin [calendar.vim](https://github.com/itchyny/calendar.vim). Those days, I decided to add the following to my `vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.tex,*.md call matchdelete(4)
autocmd BufLeave *.tex,*.md call matchadd("ErrorMsg", "\\%>80v.\\+", 10, 4)
```

This way, if I alternate to a buffer that contains a `.tex` or a `.md` file, the error after 80chars becomes disabled. If I alternate to a buffer with any other type of file, it's enabled again. The problem is, it makes most of the calendar buffer become marked with error highlighting. Simply adding `calendar` as file extension in the above code does not work.

Searching through the issues of the plugin's github, I found the following issue raised: https://github.com/itchyny/calendar.vim/issues/98. There, the plugin's author give a code snippet for making it so that the above type of error message for long lines does not display over the calendar:

```
autocmd BufEnter,FileType *
  \   if &l:filetype ==# 'calendar'
  \ |   match
  \ | else
  \ |   match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
  \ | endif
```

But with only that, I loose the ability of also having the error highlighting disabled with `tex` and `md` files. I tried the following:

```
autocmd BufEnter,FileType *
  \   if &l:filetype ==# 'calendar' || &l:filetype ==# 'tex' || &l:filetype ==# 'md'
  \ |   match
  \ | else
  \ |   match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
  \ | endif
```

However, that also does not work well. It disables the error highilghting only on the calendar buffer, not on buffers displaying tex or md files.

Then, my question. Is there a way I can have the above code modified such that I could have the error highlighting for over 80chars lines when I navigate my cursor to buffers containing any other files than tex, md or the buffer calendar?

Answer (score 1):

`&l:filetype` is not equal to file extension. For `.md` files, filetype is `markdown`, not sure what it will be for `.tex` (my Vim show `plaintext`) - so this one you will have to check in Your Vim with `:set filetype?`

So this should look something like this (change filetype for `tex`):

```
autocmd BufEnter,FileType *
  \   if index(['calendar', 'tex', 'markdown'], &filetype) > -1
  \ |   setlocal cc=
  \ | else
  \ |   setlocal cc=80
  \ | endif
```

*Edit: Shorten if statement using @Martin Tournoij comment*

Comment: You can shorten that `if` to something like: `if index(&l:filetype, ['calendar', 'tex', 'markdown']) > -1`.

Comment: The current version of your answer gives the error `E714: list required`. The original code you had there didn't throw an error, but also did not work - it's almost identical to what I had, just changed `md` with `markdown`. That was not the problem, unfortunately. It still does not work even for `tex` (whose type is indeed `tex`). Being more precise: like my original code, it works for `calendar` (i.e. alternating from/to a calendar buffer toggles the error highlighting) but not for `tex` or `markdown` files.

Comment: Order was wrong in `index`, and I switched to using colorcolumn, introduced in Vim 7.3. This code works perfectly in my Vim.